# React-data-grid as React beginner

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-data-grid

I have a task to create an app that looks like [this](http://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/examples.html#/editable). As a javascript developer I said it is a good opportunity to learn `ReactJS`. I did some `ReactJS` tutorials and also have some basic knowledge of `npm` but the Getting started page isn't very talkative and I just didn't manage to make it work.

Can somebody please make a list of commands and instructions how to start from scratch without any serious knowledge of the framework, so after `npm start` it looks like [this](http://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/examples.html#/editable)?

For example

```
cd c:\
md reactgrid
cd reactgrid
npm install react-data-grid --save
...???...
...edit index.js and add some code from...
npm start
```

Thank you.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

With create-react-app:

```
npm install -g create-react-app
create-react-app sample-grid
cd sample-grid
npm install react-data-grid
npm install react-data-grid-addons
npm install react-bootstrap
```

[Start here](http://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/examples.html#/basic), read the documentation then go to the source code:
http://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/examples.html#/basic

Paste source code into App.js, then paste the following code before your Example class:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Example />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Get your server up with `npm start` and you are set.